# How to name MUI tabs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use Material UI Tabs in react project. Code looks like this:

```
 const [tab, setTab] = useState(0);
 const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => setTab(newValue);

 return (
    <Tabs value={tab} onChange={handleTabChange}>
        <Tab label="General" />}
        <Tab label="Users" />
    <Tabs>
 )
```

How can I change it and use in state some mnemonic values like "users" and "general", but not 0 and 1? I need to have code like:

```
{tab === "users" && ... }
```

Does any body know how to set it to state and still have original functional?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `value` prop to the [`Tab`](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/) component to customize the tab value. The [`TabPanel`](https://material-ui.com/api/tab-panel/) component should be passed a matching `value` prop for the tab it corresponds to.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('general')

const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  setValue(newValue)
}
```

```
<>
  <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <Tab label="General" value="general" />
    <Tab label="Users" value="users" />
  </Tabs>

  <TabPanel value="general">
    ...
  </TabPanel>

  <TabPanel value="users">
    ...
  </TabPanel>
</>
```

[image: Edit Material tabs]